# result of splitting content of file into lines contains 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, node.js

node.js doesn't seem to have readline() method for file I/O, so I had to manually do the splitting:

```
fn='test.txt';

fs.readFile(fn, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  var array = data.toString().split('\n');
  console.log(array);
});
```

file test.txt contains 3 lines:

```
a
b
c
```

content stops right after *c* (no extra new line). However I got output as below:

```
[ 'a', 'b', 'c', '' ]
```

This confuses me. Anyone could help me out?

Comment: The title of this question doesn't seem to match. `''` is not equal to `undefined`. I believe that what you're finding is the EOF or newline character..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`''` isn’t undefined, and text files generally end with a newline, as it’s a line terminator.

```
"a\nb\nc\n".split("\n")
```

has an empty string at the end after the last `\n`.

You can slice it off (`console.log(array.slice(0, -1))`) but ignoring empty lines might be more appropriate.

Comment: indeed. although I explicitly did not appende any extra char after 'c' vim still managed to add a line terminator. interesting.

Comment: @YandongLiu: Yes, that’s really the correct format for text. It’s a line terminator, not a line separator, so vim writes one by default.

Comment: Thanks @minitech. Also verified with Python.